# Vista won't boot up. Goes to black screen with cursor

Tags: windows-vista

When I first turned on my computer today I would get a very brief and sudden blue screen which would then go away. I was prompted to run Startup Repair...I was doing the startup repair when my computer suddenly turned off. I turned it back on and now it has no blue screen but will go to a black screen before the login with just the cursor. It also won't let me do Startup repair saying there are no problems. I have no restore points so I can't do system restore. I have no CD/DVD for Vista to try, and it also won't let me boot into safe mode. What should I do?!

Comment: **You will need a system disk to resolve your problem.**  None of the solutions I have will work without one.

Answer (score 0):

The patch kb2823324 released Tuesday is causing problems. Microsoft recommends uninstalling it, and removed download links for it. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2823324, second section "Known issues with this security update"

Looks like there is an option to uninstall the patch from the command line in system recovery. See this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2839011 (last option, Option 3: Uninstall security update 2823324 at the command prompt). It's a 7 article but you should have the same options for Vista.